# Why the json is not loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

This is my html file (index.html)

This is a code for loading json file and scripting using handlebars.js
but dont know why this code is not load the json file.

```
      <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                        <div class="page-wrap">
                        <div id="data-container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    <script id="dataTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
         {{#each hospitals}}
          <h2>{{name}}</h2>
         {{/each}}
        </script>
        <script src="../js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

This is my js file (main.js)

This is a code for loading json file and scripting using handlebars.js
but dont know why this code is not load the json file.

```
     var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET','file:///C:/Users/SUBHAJIT/Desktop/Workspace/Medi-Web/WebContent/js/medi-web.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
        if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
            // This is where we'll do something with the retrieved data
            var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
            createHTML(data);
        } else {
            console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
        }
    };

    ourRequest.onerror = function() {
        console.log("Connection error");
    };
    ourRequest.send();

    function createHTML(hospitalData) {
        var rawTemplate = document.getElementById("dataTemplate").innerHTML;
        var compileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
        var ourGeneratedHTML = compileTemplate(hospitalData);
        var dataContainer = document.getElementById("data-container");
        dataContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
    }`
```

And this is my json file (medi-web.json)

```
     {
        "hospitals": [
        {
            "name": "Apollo Hospital",
            "ratings" : "four star",
            "images": "../resources/images/apollo.jpg"
        },

        {
            "name": "Amri Hospital",
            "ratings" : "two star",
            "images": "../resources/images/apollo.jpg"
        },

        {
            "name": "Fortis Hospital",
            "ratings" : "three star",
            "images": "../resources/images/apollo.jpg"
        }
        ]
    }
```

These always show connection error but why i dont know please help me how to solve? These are the code for loading json file and scripting using `handlebars.js`
    but dont know why my code is not loading the json file.

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is with the link: `file://...`.

Comment: `file://` is the equivalent to a cross-domain call, which is not allowed (by default).  If you want to develop on your local PC then can you set up a web server and use `http://localhost'?

Comment: Did you check for details of the specific error that occurred? Look at the browser console.

Comment: yes . It is the error.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/SUBHAJIT/Desktop/Workspace/Medi-Web/WebContent/js/medi-web.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reason, local file is not loaded without server.

Many old browser may support load local json file.

You must put file under local server, such as Apache, then try ajax load json file.

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.json");
xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/example.json");
```